# Pass char array by reference and return modified

Tags: c++

I have function definition lke below

```
void ConvertString(std::string &str)
{
size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find("&", pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         str.replace(pos, 1, "and");
         pos += 3;
    }
}
```

Purpose of this function is to find & and replace it with and. function execution in fine. I written this for all generalised string at one instance I am calling this in following way

```
char mystr[80] = "ThisIsSample&String";
ConvertString((std::string)mystr);
printf(mystr);
```

In above call I am expecting console should be printed with new modified string with "and".
But some of string modification is not working , any error in function?

Comment: Why not just use `std::string`? `std::string mystr = "ThisIsSample&String";`

Comment: You're using Visual C++ right? Because this shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
char mystr[80] = "ThisIsSample&String";
ConvertString((std::string)mystr);
printf(mystr);
```

… creates a temporary string object and passes that as argument.

Since the formal argument type is by reference to non-`const`, this should not compile, but Visual C++ supports it as a language extension (for class types only, IIRC).

Instead do like

```
string s = "Blah & blah";
ConvertString( s );
cout << s << endl;
```

By the way, C style casts are in general an invitation to bugs, because the basic nature of such a cast can change very silently from e.g. `const_cast` to `reinterpret_cast` when the code is maintained.

It's safe enough in the hands of an experienced programmer, like a power tool such as a chain saw can be safe in the hands of an experienced woodsman, but it's not a thing that a novice should use just to save a little work.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you create a temporary `std::string` object (whose initial content is the content of the array `mystr`), and pass that temporary object by reference to the function. This temporary object is then destructed when the call id done.

Comment: It should not even compile

Answer (score 1):

Did you read some documentation of [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and of [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)?

You need

```
std::string mystr = "ThisIsSample&String";
ConvertString(mystr);
printf(mystr.c_str());
```

You obviously want to pass by *reference* a string *variable* (technically an [l-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-value)) to your `ConvertString`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you cast char array to string.

```
ConvertString((std::string)mystr);
```

this line creates a new variable of type std::string and passes it by reference. What you want is to convert it this way:

```
std::string convertedStr = (std::string)mystr;
ConvertString(convertedStr);
printf(convertedStr.c_str());
```

I am not very well aware of C++ pointer and reference syntax, but it's similar to this

Comment: It would look less weird to say `std::string convertedStr = mystr;`

Comment: @juanchopanza (std::string)mystr makes type conversion more explicit in my opinion

Comment: If you want to be explicit you should use `std::string convertedStr = std::string(mystr);`. The C-style cast syntax looks pretty strange in C++.

Answer (score 0):

what your are doing is not correct! you <s>cannot</s> should not convert a `char*` to a `std::string` with a cstyle-cast. what you should do is more like:

```
std::string mystr( "ThisIsSample&String" );
ConvertString(mystr);
```

edit:
thx for -reputation... this code isn't even compiling... 
http://ideone.com/bCsmgf

Comment: Yes, you can. It will result in a temporary `std::string` object, constructed from the `char*`.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: thx for your answer. But IMHO it is not a question if you can, it is a question about if it's correct.... my sentense "you cannot" is not about that your are not able to do so (you are able to do so many nasty things with c++), it should say: You cannot, because it will not work this way... thx anyway

Comment: But the c-style cast is not the issue. The issue is passing an rvalue to a function taking a non-const lvalue reference. The C-style cast is just bad style.